# Finding all elements by partial Id/Css, and putting them in a list, with Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2017, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to locate all elements from a search result page and put them in a list. First problem is to find all the elements. I have no problem finding a specific element:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#event_395634"));
```

OR:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("event_395634"));
```

But how do I find every element starting with "#event_" or "event_"?

And how do I put them in a list? Is this a start?:

```
List<IWebElement> eventList = new List<IWebElement>();
events = driver.FindElements(By.?("Magic code");
```

....and then what? Or am I way off?
I intend to loop through the list at a later stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a CSS selector which selects all elements whose attribute starts with a given string.
You can use it with `By.CssSelector`.

```
var events = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("[id^=event_]"));
```

It should work.

Comment: Yes, it did! Thank you!
Do you know the answer to the second question as well? About the list?
Now I´m this far:
    `var events = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("[id^=event_]"));
    events.ToList<IWebElement>();
    foreach (object o in events)
    {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(events);
    }`